# How to print python Byte variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this byte variable

```
testByte = b"\x02\x00\x30\x03\x35"
```

I would like to print it out

I've tried:

```
listTestByte = list(testByte)
```

However, I'm getting

> [2, 0, 48, 3, 35]

I'm expecting it to be:

> [2, 0, 30, 3, 35]

Comment: The `30` in `\x30` is a hexadecimal value.  `int` values are printed using their decimal values.  What exactly is it you want to do?  What would you expect `b"\xff"` to print as?

Comment: Also since it's hexadeicmal value you should be getting `[2, 0, 48, 3, 53]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) values. So what you're getting is what you should be getting. (Except that you should be getting `[2, 0, 48, 3, 53]` and not `[2, 0, 48, 3, 35]`.)

If you want the list to have what you have in hexadecimal you can try converting it back to hexadecimal.

```
testByte = b"\x02\x00\x30\x03\x35"
listTestByte = list(testByte)
print(listTestByte)             # [2, 0, 48, 3, 53]
listTestByteAsHex = [int(hex(x).split('x')[-1]) for x in listTestByte]
print(listTestByteAsHex)        # [2, 0, 30, 3, 35]
```

Or use string operations, to split at '\x' depending on your purpose.

Comment: Thx. I'm hitting "invalid literal for int () with base 10" for listTestByte with value [2,0,53,3,0,0,0,3,61]. Why is it so?

Comment: Hexadecimal values range from 0-9 and a-f. And 61 in decimal is 3D in hex. So that doesn't convert to int. So remove `int()` to get the value as string. If you still need 61 then I'd suggest using string operations.